# symbol for \not is sometimes rendered vertically

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, amssymb

I hope this question is not a duplicate, but after some research I haven't found anything related to the argument.

My problem is the following. I've noticed that when I use `\not` in conjunction with some of the standard mathematical symbols (such as `\models` and `\subseteq)`, the resulting bar is vertical, and not diagonal as I usually find it in books and papers.

I'm using the `llncs` document class, and the packages `amsmath`, `amsfonts`, and `amssymb`.

The fun fact is, the bar crossing the `\nVdash` symbol from `amssymb` is correctly diagonal, HOWEVER the bar displayed in `$\nsubseteq$` (from the same package) is vertical.

Is there a way to have my diagonal bars back?

Thanks.

================

Oddly enough, I can't replicate the problem in a new document. Maybe one of my macros is messing things up?

================

Problem solved. I was actually importing mathabx, in one of the macros file. Thank you very much!

Comment: do you mean `\not` or pre composed negations such as `\nsubseteq` where it's the choice of the font designer?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's impossible to give any kind of advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are using `mathabx`, which also have vertical negation bars in its symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\[\nVdash\nsubseteq\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Without package `mathabx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\[\nVdash\nsubseteq\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Without mathabx]

BTW, class `llncs` seems unrelated, thus I have replaced it with the standard `article` class.

Comment: I'm not use mathabx :\. I thought I could use its \changenotsign but it has no effect on the symbols. I'll add a minimal working example in my question.

Comment: Solved. In effect, I was using a macros file that imports mathabx. Thank you very much for your help!!!